# ADM-3A ASCII animation issue, refresh rate?

Tags: terminal, serial-port, debian, refresh, ascii

I have an ADM-3A serial terminal hooked up to my Debian server. I know it's cliche, but I really want to watch the towel.blinkenlights.nl Star Wars ASCII animation on it. The problem is that the animation doesn't display properly, I can connect but the frames scroll up the screen as opposed to refreshing properly. There is a video on youtube of someone doing exactly what I want to do, so I know it's possible. Any ideas?